# Is there any way to use bitmap fonts in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, bitmap

I am working on a retro-style game which has an intentionally pixelated aesthetic.  I need the kinds of things provided by Swing (text fields, areas, buttons, list boxes, etc).

Is there any way to change the look and feel of Swing components to use bitmap style fonts?  I don't care if they are actually bitmap fonts or not. I'd be perfectly happy with something like C64_Pro (http://style64.org/c64-truetype).

I want to be able to precisely control the width and height of everything (font characters, component borders, etc) in pixels.  I don't want any antialiasing or rasterization, and I want the appearance to be the same across devices at the pixel level.

Is this possible?  All the solutions I've seen for using bitmap fonts have been custom code for drawing strings on Graphics2D using images and the like.  I'd really like to avoid that.

Point of clarification:

I don't care if the result is rendered in actual pixels or not (since that might make it very small on high res devices).  What's important is that the screen can be divided into perfectly square pixel-like regions that are the same on every device.  So it's ok if a "logical pixel" is actually several real pixels in size, as long as it's perfectly square, doesn't bleed its color into its neighbors, and every device shows the same number of logical pixels in the same place.

Comment: You can download http://www.dafont.com/8-bit-1-6.font and use the createFont() method on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html to load it. To calculate font sizes look at the `FontMetrics` class.

Comment: I've tried approaches like this, but it's not ideal for several reasons.

Firstly, there's no way to set the font dimensions in pixels, only "font points" which are measured in inches.  You can do some experimentation to figure out how many font points are needed to get the right dimensions in pixels, but this number may be different for different devices.

Secondly, even when you get the value right, you still get artifacts like the blue and yellow lines in this picture (magnified to 4x): https://postimg.org/image/6t2z0bhjr/

Comment: Take a look at this class https://github.com/Nibby/Pix/blob/master/src/me/nibby/pix/BitmapFont.java. There is no drawing on any images, they are just loaded. Would this do what you want?

Comment: If it doesn't extend java.awt.Font, I don't think I can use it in Swing components.